# How to commit only changes between two arbitrary commits to a branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

I have the problem that I have done my development on a wrong branch and now I want to take / cherry-pick my changes and put / rebase them on a different branch. I only want to take the text lines which has been changed, nothing more!

Here an example to illustrate my problem:

```
C3 <-- Branch 1
|
C2    C4 <-- Master
|      |
C1 ----|
```

Each commit (C1,...,C4) contains a text file with the following content:

```
C1:
A

C2:
A
B

C3:
A
B
C

C4:
A2
```

I want to put the changes between commit C2 and C3 onto commit C4. This means I want to take the line which has been changed (C) and put it on commit C4. The text file of the new commit C5 should look like this:

```
C5:
A2

C
```

If I type in on the master branch

```
git cherry-pick C2..C3
```

I get a conflict and meld opens which the following view:

```
LOCAL:         BASE              REMOTE
A2                               A
                                 B
                                 C
```

This is not what I want. I only want to see the differences between C2 and C3. So it should look like this which is a lot easier to merge:

```
LOCAL:         BASE              REMOTE
A2                               

                                 C
```

Is this possible in Git or is there a merge tool which supports this work flow? It makes things so much easier.

Comment: Presumably your real situation is more complex than this? If not, this would be trivial to fix by hand.

Comment: I just want to give a simple example to illustrate my problem. My real situation is much more complex and I am searching for a solution which is not so error-prone than do everything manually.

Comment: What happens when you just try using `git cherry-pick C3` instead of `git cherry-pick C2..C3`? I can't remember if the range `C2..C3` is inclusive or exclusive of C2 in the case of cherry-pick, I'll have to test it out later.

Comment: @Cupcake: git cherry-pick C3-commit-hash leads to the same results.

Comment: @user3625015 hmmm, that doesn't seem right. I'll have to try it myself later. What about just getting a diff with `git diff C2 C3 > diff.patch`, then applying it to the other branch with `git apply diff.patch`?

Comment: @Cupcake: git apply gives me the error message "error: patch failed: test.txt:1\n error: test.txt: patch does not apply" :(

Comment: @user3625015 that wouldn't be much useful using any mergetool since you'd be comparing two different files. Also please note that mergetool compares files - there are no files in your project that consist only changes between commits. However you could try something like this `git format-patch -U0 C2..C3` and then `patch -p1 -f < patch_name'. It will generete the patch only with lines that were changed and then try to apply them on the exact same lines in your master branch.